# I need to update android app for new version

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have android app calendar. I need to update it because it is`nt working in new android devices. What should i do for it after upgrading gradle version i have this problems:

```
1) cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.
2)cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension-level'. No child element is expected at this point.
3)cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension-level'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
4)cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension-level'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.
5)Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments [android_release_aar_dulkhoq89m33wxqb89a5btma5$_run_closure4@7da75b2f] on project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: You probably updated Gradle or a plugin. You need to find out where this `uploadArchives` method came from, then check that plugin's documentation to see what replaced it.

Comment: Such problems can not be solved by just looking at the error message.

Comment: Thank u for help, ill try